# Eloquent with not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I am having this problem with the laravel eloquent with.
This code (in the docs) `$debtHistory = DebtHistory::with('user.firstname')->get();` seems to not work, because it returns something lik `Call to undefined relationship [firstname] on model [App\User].` what am I doing wrong here? Any idea? Thank you guys. :)

Note: If this helps.

I actually have an alternative method but I would like to do it in one query. This code my help you to know what I am trying to do.

```
$debtHistory = DebtHistory::whereBetween('created_at',[$filterData['from'], $filterData['to']])->where('amount', '>', '0')->get();
$excelData = [];
foreach($debtHistory as $history) {
     array_push($excelData, ['Name' => $history->user->firstname .' '. $history->user->lastname, 'Debt' => $history->amount, 'Date' => Carbon::parse($history->created_at)->format('Y-m-d')]);
}
```

I want to do that process in a eloquent model query is that possible?

Comment: can you tell me how your debt_histories and users table are related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error says that `User` model doesn't have `firstname` relationship defined. You should load the data like this:

```
$debtHistory = DebtHistory::with('user')->get();
```

And display it with something like this:

```
@foreach ($debtHistory as $one)
    {{ $one->user->firstname }}
@endforeach
```

This will work if `user()` has `belongsTo()` relationship.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm not going for an foreach i'm planning to get the columns of user from my belongsTo relationship in debtHistory and store them in one eloquent collection returned from the query, is the WITH the correct way? or am I in another page?

Comment: @KeannuAlforqueAtilano because you're using `get()`, you'll get a collection of many `DebtHistory` objects. Each object will have related `User` object. SO you have to iterate over a collection to get the data.

Comment: @KeannuAlforqueAtilano you're iterating over a collection in your code. The code you posted will create N+1 queries, so you should use `with()` like I've shown. In this case Laravel will create just two queries and `$history->user->firstname` will take the data from the collection.

Comment: can you tell me how your debt_histories and users table are related?

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @Learner belongsTo relationship. from debt to user.